# working with option of $query in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

i want use where for $query.

```
  foreach ($oppId as $o) {

                        $id = $o['opportunity_id'];


                        $query->Where("id=$id");


                }
```

When I use this. All items shown

```
 $query->orWhere("id=$id");
```

i need get this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `opportunity` WHERE id =27 or id =28
```

this is all of my function :

```
 public function actionShow($type = 0, $city = 0, $client = 0) {

    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['*'])->from('opportunity ')->innerJoin('profile_details', 'opportunity.user_id=profile_details.user_id')->orderBy('id desc');
    $query->Where('id !=-1');

    if (isset($_REQUEST['type'])) {
        $type = $_REQUEST['type'];



        if ($type != 0) {
            $query->andWhere("project_type_id=$type");
        }
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['city'])) {
        $city = $_REQUEST['city'];


        if ($city != 0) {
            $query->andWhere("state_id=$city");
        }
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['client'])) {
        $client = $_REQUEST['client'];


        if ($client != 0) {

            $oppId = \app\models\OpportunityControl::find()
                    ->where('project_type_id = :project_type_id', [':project_type_id' => $client])
                    ->all();

            foreach ($oppId as $o) {


                    $id = $o['opportunity_id'];
                    $query->orWhere("id=$id");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very much do not want to use strings to add to the query under any circumstances as that is ripe for SQL injection.  I'd format it like this:

```
...
$params = [];
foreach ($oppId as $o) {
    $params[] = $o->opportunity_id;
}
$query->andWhere(['in', 'id', $params]);
...
```

You should also adjust your other query params so that you are not passing variables into SQL via a string.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['type'])) {
    $type = $_REQUEST['type'];

    if ($type != 0) {
        $query->andWhere(['project_type_id' => $type]);
    }
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['city'])) {
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'];

    if ($city != 0) {
        $query->andWhere(['state_id' => $city]);
    }
}
```

See the [Yii2 guide on using variables in queries](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where) for what you are trying to avoid here.  Specifically:

> Do NOT embed variables directly in the condition like the following, especially if the variable values come from end user inputs, because this will make your application subject to SQL injection attacks.
>
> `// Dangerous! Do NOT do this unless you are very certain $status must be an integer.
>   $query->where("status=$status");`

Answer (score 0):

I do it with Arrays

```
$query->where(['or',['id'=>27],['id'=>28]]);
```

But in your case save all ids in a Array is not possible,I do it with string inside foreach

```
    $StringWhere='';
    $LastElement = end($oppId);
       foreach ($oppId as $o) 
            {
                    $id = $o['opportunity_id'];
                    $StringWhere.=' id='.$id;
                    if($o!=$LastElement)
                    {
                      $StringWhere.=' or ';
                    }
            }
    $query->where($StringWhere);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->where(['or',['id'=>27],['id'=>28]]);
```

I use this and it works perfectly as mentioned by metola. :)